# Pycharm Community Edition - Django-Admin Command Not Recognized

Tags: django, pycharm, python-venv

I cannot start my PyCharm project via the django-admin command. The terminal doesn't recognize it. Details:

1.) I have the package installed in Python. And it is installed in my project.

2.) It seems to be installed 2 levels down from the project directory, in \venv\Scripts. But the command isn't recognized there either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share what command do you use?

Comment: PyCharm try (rightfully) to force to use virtual environments. check that you have setup one for your project, and you open the terminal either in PyCharm (and right project) or you activate the virtual environment on the terminal. Also: initial working directory could not be what do you expect (is django admin command in PATH?). And not all systems understand `#!` files, so you may need to prefix `python` to the command. In any case your question lacks details: which terminal, which error, did you tried outside PyCharm? (which it is just an IDE).